# Cannot instantiate the type Pair not abstract

Tags: java, collections

A wierd error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Cannot instantiate the type Pair
> at Array2$TestIterator.next(Array2.java:31)
> at t1.main(t1.java:6)
> "

here my code:

```
public class Array2 implements Iterable<Pair> {
    private int[] a;
    public Array2(int[] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<Pair> iterator() {
        
        return new TestIterator(this);
    }
    
    
    public class TestIterator<Pair> implements Iterator<Pair> { 
        private Pair p;
        int i=0,j=0;
        // constructor 
        TestIterator(Array2 obj) { 
            // initialize cursor 
            
        } 
          
        // Checks if the next element exists 
        public boolean hasNext() { 
            return i<a.length&&j<a.length;
        } 
          
        // moves the cursor/iterator to next element 
        public Pair next() { 
            Pair p=new Pair(4,6);/// here error <---------------
            return p;
        } 
          
        // Used to remove an element. Implement only if needed 
        public void remove() { 
            // Default throws UnsupportedOperationException. 
        } 
    } 
}
```

and Pair class:

```
public class Pair {
    private int x, y;
    public Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well .. you shouldn't run code, that does not compile beforehand. Please tell us the (complete) compiler error!

Comment: Your `Array2` class contains `public class TestIterator<Pair> implements Iterator<Pair> {` which declares its own *generic type* named `<Pair>` at `class TestIterator<Pair>`. You probably want to change it to `public class TestIterator implements Iterator<Pair>`. For now that fragment behaves as if it was written like `public class TestIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{... public T next(){ T p=new T(4,6); return p}..}` but compiler can't make guarantee what type `T` will represent, or if that type will have required constructor.